# XML encoding UTF-16 using PHP ( I keep getting UTF-8)

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I have a PHP script that extracts an XML file from a MYSQL. I have the following line:

```
$xml='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>;
```

But the extracted file is being recognized as UTF-8 UNIX (LF):
[image]

I need to have the encoding as UTF-16 and Windows CLRF. What is the correct syntax?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: is that file stored in mysql or created using a php extension like e.g. simplexml?

Comment: That isn't UTF-16 though, I don't see any null bytes. Are you sure you're encoding it as UTF-16?

Comment: @Hajo This is created with PHP code only, no extensions or mysql.

Comment: php with utf-16 is not funny, i've already given up on it, sorry ^^

Comment: This is indeed not UTF-16. The header is simply wrong :)

Answer (score 1):

add a HTTP header:

```
header('Content-type: text/xml; charset=utf-16')
```

I'm not sure if text/xml is the best for you, you should decide it: http://www.petefreitag.com/item/381.cfm

Also, your editor in the screenshot is set to UTF-8